# Visual Studio Code - Xdebug won't work

Tags: php, macos, xampp, visual-studio-code, xdebug

In Visual Studio Code (1.9.1) (mac) i have setup the *php-debug* plugin.

In the debug screen i start '*listen for Xdebug*'.
After this i open the index.php on my XAMPP server (local).
But nothing happens.

- the blue bar at the bottom of the screen turns orange.
- the step over, step into and step out buttons are greyed out.
- Also the following error message occurs at the watched variables:
  **cannot evaluate code without an connection**

I try to use breakpoints on the following code:

```
<?php
$i = 0;

do {
$i++;
if (!($i % 1)) {
    echo('<p>$i = ' . $i . '</p>');
    }
}
while ($i < 100);
?>
```

I am using XAMPP and in my **php.ini** file i use port 9000 for Xdebug.

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php71-xdebug/2.5.0/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote.port=9000
```

I installed Xdebug using homebrew.
Here is my php info:
[phpinfo.htm](http://trapce.net16.net/phpinfo.htm)
[Xdebug wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) tells me Xdebug is installed correctly.

my **launch.json** file looks like this:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "log": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
]
}
```

Would anyone know what i am doing wrong?

After setting the `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` in the ini file
as n00dl3 suggested debugging most of the time works, but once in a while i get the following
error in the debug console:

```
<- threadEvent
ThreadEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'thread',
  body: { reason: 'exited', threadId: 1 } }
```

Comment: did you try to set  `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` in your ini file ?

Comment: It seems to work most of the time now, but once in a while i get the following error in the debug console:
   ` <- threadEvent
    ThreadEvent {
      seq: 0,
      type: 'event',
      event: 'thread',
      body: { reason: 'exited', threadId: 1 } }`

Comment: No idea about that

Comment: [seems related](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1703)

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this problem as well, not with the same environment (NGINX server + `php-fpm`) but the same symptoms. It turned out to be caused by my `xdebug` configuration.

**How I managed to diagnose it** : by writing a simple PHP script for test just like OP did :

```php
<?php

xdebug_info();
```

By browsing to it, I got a bunch of info on my setup, including :

```
xdebug.client_host => localhost
xdebug.client_port => 9003
```

whereas my xdebug was listening on port 9900 (default being 9000).

**Steps to fix** : just add the following lines to your `php.ini` or `xdebug.ini` (wherever the rest of your xdebug configuration lies) :

```
# This should match your xdebug.remote_host
xdebug.client_host=localhost
# This should match your xdebug.remote_port
xdebug.client_port=9900
xdebug.mode=debug
```

Then rerun a debug session in VScode, add some breakpoints, and re-browse to your script : my VScode window popped up, the execution was paused on the breakpoint and the variables where accessible in the debug pannel just like expected.

**EDIT** : don't forget to also :

- add `xdebug.mode=debug` to your `php.ini`
- restart webserver and `php-fpm` services.

Answer (score 2):

It seemed the server root needed to be set
in the launch.json with **localSourceRoot** like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "log": true,
            "localSourceRoot": "http://127.0.0.1/public_html/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Now breakpoints are working like they should.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem too.

Somehow, someday, without realizing it, I got version 3 of xdebug installed, and a lot of conf param name changed , see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776338/xdebug-3-the-setting-xdebug-remote-has-been-renamed-see-the-upgrading-g)

So verifying the xdebug version with phpinfo for example can be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, these two lines were missing from the php.ini file.

```
 xdebug.mode = debug
 xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working with `VSCODE devcontainer` and I fix with the config below:

My launch.json for VSCODE

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
}
```

I use `Dockerfile` with a RUN below to install xdebug:

```
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

I find my xdebug config file in `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini`

I edit the file as below:

```
zend_extension=xdebug

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
```

Or you can add it in Dockfile like below:

```
RUN echo ' \n[xdebug] \n\
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal  \n\
xdebug.mode=debug  \n\
xdebug.start_with_request=yes \n\
xdebug.idekey="VSCODE"  \n\
\n' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

`mode` This setting controls which Xdebug features are enabled. We’ve set `develop` to enable development aids, such as getting better error messages, and `debug` to enable step debugging.

`client_host` This setting tells Xdebug the IP address or hostname of the machine that is running your text editor or IDE.

`start_with_request` This setting determines whether a function trace, garbage collection statistics, profiling, or step debugging are activated at the start of a PHP request. Setting it to yes instructs Xdebug to always initiate a debugging session.

Answer (score 0):

Check xdebug.client_port
in page xdebug_info(); or phpinfo();

Config same port in launch.json of vscode