# Xdebug 3 - The setting 'xdebug.remote_***' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I just installed Xdebug v3.0.0beta1 on my OSX and tried to use it on PhpStorm 2020.1, but I get this :

> Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_enable' has been renamed,
> see the upgrading guide at
> https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_enable
> (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED) Xdebug: [Config]
> The setting 'xdebug.remote_host' has been renamed, see the upgrading
> guide at
> https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_host (See:
> https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED) Xdebug: [Config] The
> setting 'xdebug.remote_mode' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide
> at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_mode
> (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED) Xdebug: [Config]
> The setting 'xdebug.remote_port' has been renamed, see the upgrading
> guide at
> https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_port

And the links provided lead to nothing but an image with bugs.

My question is what are the right settings to set and where to actually change them since i have nothing about xdebug in my php.ini file.

Comment: 1) What is your PhpStorm version? 2) So .. what is your question?

Comment: @LazyOne I updated my post

Comment: What is your PhpStorm version EXACTLY please. "2020" is not a version. It's either 2020.1.x, 2020.2.x or 2020.3

Comment: download a 2.9 version from https://xdebug.org/download/historical

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xdebug 3 will be supported from PhpStorm **2020.3** version only, which is currently in EAP stage (Early Access Program) and will be released in about 1 month time.

For the moment you will have to either stick to Xdebug 2.9 for your 2020.1 IDE version or try latest 2020.3 EAP build: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/

Xdebug 3 is supported in the most recent **EAP #6** build: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/11/phpstorm-2020-3-eap-6/

---

As for the Xdebug 3 upgrade in terms of making changes for Xdebug settings (php.ini) -- check this link: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

---

**You CAN use your 2020.1 PhpStorm with Xdebug 3 if you wish -- just configure Xdebug 3 properly.**

It works fine for me with Xdebug 3.0.0beta1, PHP 7.4 x64 on Windows 10 -- see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64820427/783119

Those errors that you see indicate that you still have Xdebug 2 config values in your php.ini.

Comment: previous xdebug releases https://xdebug.org/download/historical

Answer (score 46):

PhpStorm 2020.3 supports XDebug3. There is a [detailed upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) on how to change your settings properly.

In my case (using Docker), I had to change the settings

from:

```
; v2.*

[Xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=off
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal

;# 9000 is default (not required to set).
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

to:

```
; v3.*

[Xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal

;# 9003 is now the default (set this for old PhpStorm settings).
xdebug.client_port=9000
```

Comment: xdebug.start_with_request=yes
was what I had to do. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

My php -v

```
PHP 7.2.34-8+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2020 16:57:33) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.34-8+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

I got Xdebug v3 working with PHPStorm 2020.2.3 with these steps:

1. `export XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM`
2. Update php.init file

   ```
   xdebug.extension=/usr/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so <== path to your xdebug.so file
   #xdebug.remote_autostart=1
   xdebug.start_with_request=yes
   #xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
   xdebug.discover_client_host=true
   xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 3600
   #xdebug.remote_enable = 1
   #xdebug.remote_host = localhost
   xdebug.client_host=localhost
   #xdebug.remote_port = 9000
   xdebug.client_port = 9000
   xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
   xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
   xdebug.mode = debug
   ```

   '#' is old version (Xdebug 2.x)
3. Reset apache2: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have PHP Storm 2020.2 and haven't changed anything in the IDE side, however, in the server side I have to change a few things

In order to enable Xdebug 3 you need to set `xdebug.mode = debug` for step debugging

In my particular server config I have set it like this:

- /etc/php/7.3/cgi/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

> zend_extension=xdebug.so

- /etc/php/7.3/cgi/conf.d/21-xdebug-mgs.ini

> xdebug.mode = debug

Then in my .user.ini in the root of my website I have set this:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.client_host = "10.0.0.2"
xdebug.client_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_connect_back = false
xdebug.log = '/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/j39vm36/administrator/logs/xdebug.log'
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.output_dir = '/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/j39vm36/administrator/logs/'
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
```

Comment: are these xdebug 3 or v2 configurations? TY

Answer (score 0):

I had `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` in my php.ini / xdebug.conf but it needed to be `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` (without spaces) for it to actually work. (macos ventura, php 8.0)