# Connection was not established Xdebug 3 with PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, php-8

Good afternoon.

When an attempt is made to debug the script on PHP 8, PhpStorm reports that there is no connection with version 3 xdebug. Works with all versions below 3. I tried to change the parameters of xdebug.remote_{host, port} to xdebug.client_{host, port} but also did not help.

Comment: What is your IDE version exactly?

Comment: PhpStorm 2020.2.3

Comment: Xdebug 3 will be supported from PhpStorm 2020.3 version only, which is currently in EAP stage (Early Access Program) and will be released in about 1 month time. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64777506/783119

Comment: I installed PhpStorm 2020.3 and saw that the PhpStorm 2020.2 was not adding some flags due to which the connection did not work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xdebug 3 will be fully supported in PhpStorm **2020.3** version only, which is currently in EAP stage (Early Access Program) and will be released in about 1 month time.

It is already supported in the most recent **EAP #6** build: check this blog post for more info: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/11/phpstorm-2020-3-eap-6/

---

I have downloaded Xdebug 3.0.0beta1 for my PHP 7.4 on Windows 10, configured it from scratch (using correct Xdebug 3 config values: https://3.xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide and https://3.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) ... and **it still works fine in PhpStorm 2020.2.3**.

Yes, IDE sends old-style parameters when initiating debugging for a CLI script (like `xdebug.remote_{host, port}` etc) but the debug still works just fine.

This is my php.ini content for Xdebug 3 settings (as simple as this):

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port = 9001
xdebug.mode = debug
```

*(I have a bit mores settings, but those are customisation for output file names, log locations, extra stuff for quickly turn on some options in some scenarios/when needed etc -- these are not needed here and it works fine without them)*
[image]

CLI debug initiated from IDE ("PHP Script" type of configuration):
[image]

That's what IDE is executing: `E:\Projects\php\php74\php.exe -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9001 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 E:\Projects\web\_idetest\test.php`. As you may see these old style parameters do not affect Xdebug 3 at all.

P.S. If I set `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` in php.ini then debug will work even for Run (or when executing that PHP script outside of IDE) -- as long as "phone handle" icon is green (IDE listens for incoming debug requests).

Comment: Just the same change php.ini I forgot to do, I thought the change of conf.d/20-xdebug.ini will be connected