# Xdebug 3 & PhpStorm 2020.2.4

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

I get this error when using Xdebug version **3** with PhpStorm version **2020.2.4** :

```
Connection was not established. 
Cannot start debugger session with 'Xdebug 3.0.0' Validate installation
```

php.ini Config:

```ini
xdebug.mode=develop
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port=9003
```

Comment: You shoudl provide more info: 1) Your OS 2) What are you trying to debug: a CLI script or a web page? 3) Show Xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output captured in the same way as you are trying to debug. `xdebug_info()` output will print just that as well. 4) What Xdebug log has to say about it 5) Screenshots are welcome as well.

Comment: BTW, AFAIK the `develop` mode (`xdebug.mode=develop`) does not establish any debugger sessions. It's for runtime helpers/extra error info etc: https://xdebug.org/docs/develop . For actual debugging/breakpoints you need `debug` mode.

Comment: P.S. Xdebug 3 is fully supported from **2020.3** version only -- released today. The validation screen in 2020.2 may show not set values etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65091404/783119

Comment: Follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776338/xdebug-3-the-setting-xdebug-remote-has-been-renamed-see-the-upgrading-g/65407343#65407343

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xdebug 3 is fully supported from 2020.3 version only.

Comment: Supporting documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/2020-3/ . Thank you very much @Mateo - thought I was losing my mind for a moment :)